# How can i hide class contain specific value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

How can i hide a the text under class named `amount` using `javascript` or `php`?

```
<span class="amount">$0.00</span>
```

I tried the following but no luck

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(".amount:has(a:contains('$0.00'))").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to hide it only if its content is `$0.00` ?

Comment: @lliev Correct that what i want

Answer (score 2):

Assuming jQuery based on code in original question.

Your original script was close. All you really need is:

```
$('.amount:contains($0.00)').hide()
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

### Bonus

If you can't use jQuery, here's how to do it the old fashioned way.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('amount'), function (e) {
  if (e.innerText == '$0.00') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

Setting styles is JavaScript isn't too clean, so the better thing to do would be to set a class, with corresponding CSS to hide elements matching that class. For example `e.classList.add('hidden');` and `.hidden { display: none; }`

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach (IE 9+)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList (IE 10+)

Comment: I think you are missing a quote.

Comment: @Rick Viscomi Thanks here is my link http://fn.nudigitalmarketingagency.com/product/barbeque-pork-spareribs-2/ none of the solutions are  not working for me may be i miss something i am using a plugin for this part

Comment: $ is undefined. But you have access to the jQuery object, so you could use `jQuery('.amount:contains($0.00)').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<script>
// Assign object
var AmtObj  =   $(".amount");
// Get contents
var Amount  =   AmtObj.html();
// If equals '$0.00', hide
if(Amount == '$0.00') {
    AmtObj.hide();
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
var item = $(".amount");
if(item.html() === "$0.00"){
    item.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot of trouble for what you want especially if you wanna extract the numbers without the formatting.

If you control the data add a `data-value` to your attribute and put the raw number their such as `<span class="amount" data-value='0.00'>$0.00</span>`  and then select it and hide it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".amount:contains('$0.00')").hide();    
});
```